# How to obtain the Stripe chargeID

Tags: node.js, stripe-payments

So I am making a payment on the Stripe test environment through using their API, I use the below to create a payment.

```
const createPayment = await stripe.customers.create
```

when printing createPayment object, there is no chargeID value.

I want to obtain this value so i can make a stripe transfer using the following:

```
const transfer = stripe.transfers.create({
                    amount: amountToPay,
                    currency: 'gbp',
                    source_transaction: {{chargeID}},
                    destination: stripeID,
                });
```

I have looked through the Stripe docs and online and I can't seem to find how this is found.
Does anyone know how to find the chargeID anywhere ?

Answer (score 0):

[stripe.customers.create](https://stripe.com/docs/api/customers/create?lang=node) is used to create a Customer.

To create a payment, you should [create a PaymentIntent](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents/create) instead.

Example

```
const paymentIntent = await stripe.paymentIntents.create({
  amount: 2000,
  currency: 'usd',
  confirm: true,
  payment_method: 'pm_card_amex_threeDSecureNotSupported',
});
```

Once the PaymentIntent's `status='succeeded'`, you can use the charge `id` that can be found in [charges.data](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents/object#payment_intent_object-charges-data).

Example

```
{
  "id": "pi_...",
  "object": "payment_intent",
  "amount": 2000,
  "currency": "usd",
  "last_payment_error": null,
  "livemode": false,
  "next_action": null,
  "payment_method": "pm_...",
  "status": "succeeded",
  ...
  "charges": {
    "object": "list",
    "data": [
      {
        "id": "ch_...",
        "object": "charge",
        "amount": 2000,
        ...
}
```

Additional resources that may be useful :

- https://stripe.com/docs/payments/intents
- https://stripe.com/docs/testing
- https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment
- https://stripe.com/docs/connect/charges-transfers

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the chargeID from within the stripe.charges.create object

code snippet below.

```
const chargeObject = await stripe.charges.create({
            amount: product.price * 100,
            currency: 'GBP',
            customer: customer.id,
            receipt_email: token.email,
            description: product.name
        }, { idempotencyKey: idempotencyKey })
        chargeID = chargeObject.id
    })
```